# Gulp browserSync keeps scrolling to top after reload

Tags: gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

I have a problem with Gulp and BrowserSync, is really a small issue but is bugging me.

Every time I change the scss file and I ran sass() to combile it the browser reloads and scrolls back to the top.

Is there a way to prevent the browser to do that every time I change a scss file?

By the way this is happening only on the sass task, the js and php tasks do not cause the browser to scroll to the top.

I tried Chrome and Firefox and I get the same behavior.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "mysite.dev"
    });

    gulp.watch("styles/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("*scripts/*.js", ['js']);
    gulp.watch("*.php", ['php']);
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("styles/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("styles/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('scripts/*.js')
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
gulp.task('php', function() {
    return gulp.src('*.php')
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Is there a way to stop that?

Answer (score 1):

**Update** - Two days later and I can't reproduce the issue anymore. Not sure if below code actually solved it.

**Solution:** Appending `.on('change', browserSync.reload)` to your Gulp Sass watch line should stop your browser scroll from resetting when saving a SCSS file.

*(Note - Gulp v4)*

```
gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', sassCompile).on('change', browserSync.reload) // Gulp v4 version
```

**gulpfile.js example:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
const { series } = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

function serve(){
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "./"
    },
  });
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', sassCompile).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./css/*.css').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("./*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}
exports.serve = serve;

function sassCompile(cb) {
  return gulp
      .src('./scss/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
  cb();
}
exports.sass = sassCompile;

exports.default = series(serve);
```

**To run**: Enter in command line

```
gulp
```